# Show button if two conditions are met

Tags: php, html

So I have a button that I want to show and hide on certain parts.
So if `$unlockcourse` is false AND the `$courseid` is 1, I would like the button to be hidden, BUT I would like it to be shown at all other times no matter what the `courseid`is

```
      $courseid = ($userinfo['course']) * 1;
      $mycourse = ($userinfo['id_course']) * 1;
       $unlockcourse = true;
        if($haspaid == 1){
            $unlockcourse = false;
        } else if ($haspaid == 0) {
            $unlockcourse = true;   
        }

    <?php if ($unlockcourse == false && $mycourse >= 1) { ?> 
     <a href="course-work-proc.php" class="btn btn-primary">Resume Course</a>
      <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you actually want to do is show it if unlockcourse is false, and mycourse is 1. This means that to find out when to show it, you need to negate both conditions like this:

```
 <?php if (!($unlockcourse == false && $mycourse == 1)) { ?> 
     <a href="course-work-proc.php" class="btn btn-primary">Resume Course</a>
      <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised how did this not throw an error. The error lies here:

```
if ($unlockcourse == false) && if ($mycourse == 1) && {
```

It should be:

```
if ($unlockcourse == false && $mycourse == 1) {
```

Comment: Can you help me? I have edit the original question with the updated code. So I have a button that I want to show and hide on certain parts. So if $unlockcourse is false AND the $courseid is 1 I would like the button to be hidden, BUT I would like it to be shown at all other times. no matter what the courseid is

Comment: You missed one change when you updated the course: it's $mycourse == 1 (equal, not greater or equal than)

Comment: It's still not showing... I have in my database id_course at 0 and haspaid at 0 and the button isnt showing

Comment: Works better but its doing the opposite of what I need. If id_course is 0 and has paid is 0 is doesn't show up at all. I need it to show up if id_course is 0 and has paid is 0. I need it to go away if id_course is 1 and has paid is 0. I need it to show if id course is 1+ and has paid is 1

Comment: @SkyHopper Confused... `:(`

Answer (score 1):

Try Editing the following code

```
 <?php if ($unlockcourse == false && $mycourse >= 1) { ?> 
     <a href="course-work-proc.php" class="btn btn-primary">Resume Course</a>
      <?php } ?>
```

into

```
         <?php if !($unlockcourse == false && $mycourse >= 1){
         echo "<a href='course-work-proc.php' class='btn btn-primary'>Resume Course</a>";
}?>
```

This will make the button appear when your statements are true, and nothing will appear when the statement is false

Comment: It's doing the same thing, I need to it only hide if $unlockcourse == false and mycourse is 1 I want it to show any other time. So if unlockcourse is true and my course is 1 it shows. but if unlockcourse is false and mycourse is 1 it wont show. If unlock course is true and mycourse is 5 it will show, etc

Comment: Sorry My Bad, I forgot to close the parenthesis, The code is edited and should work fine now

Comment: Try Now, I have added a not statement there "!",

Comment: Works better but its doing the opposite of what I need. If id_course is 0 and has paid is 0 is doesn't show up at all. I need it to show up if id_course is 0 and has paid is 0. I need it to go away if id_course is 1 and has paid is 0. I need it to show if id course is 1+ and has paid is 1

Comment: Please check your if statement again.

Comment: i copied and pasted exactly what you gave me

Comment: if !($unlockcourse == false  it doesn't let me do this. It wants me to do (!$

Comment: No it does what I said above